# PHP `continue` not working as expected

Tags: php

The problem I'm having is that PHP isn't handling my `continue` correctly. My code is as follows:

```
$count = -1;
foreach ($lines as $item){
    $count++;

    if ($item == ""){
        continue;  // don't process empty items
    }
    if ($count > 0){
        echo '-not the first line-';
    }

    switch ($item){
        case "item1":
            echo "item 1 found";
        break;
    }
}
```

The `if ($count > 0)` part executes regardless of where the `continue` is placed before it, but the `switch` executes as expected.

If I remove the `if ($count > 0)` and place it **inside** the switch, it executes as expected:

```
    switch ($item){
        case "item1":
            if ($count > 0){
                echo '-not the first line-';  // executes as expected
            }
            echo "item 1 found";
        break;
    }
```

Is this normal? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the contents of `$lines`?

Comment: continue in this case will only execute if your $item is "", is it so?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/cKTFYH

Comment: nope, nothing after `continue` should be executed; I would recommend using `if ( empty( trim( $item ) )` instead of ( `$item == '' )` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: What is $item actually? It might be a newline, which doesn't equal "" afaik.

Comment: If `$item == ""`, you still increment the counter, so an empty item still counts as one. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Vague: $lines always either contains strings sent from ajax such "John Doe" or "2011", or empty strings.

Comment: never use empty. Instead use if (trim($item)=='')

Comment: @yes123 What's wrong with `empty()`?

Comment: @MickHansen: doesn't contain any newlines, and have tried 'trim' etc

Comment: @Juhana: yes, it is intentional

Comment: if you do empty() on an undifenied var it will not raise E_NOTICE. empty is considered a bad pratice

Comment: It's rather harsh to say "never use empty()". It's perfectly ok if you want to check whether the variable is either undefined or empty (or, defined and non-empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The if ($count > 0) part executes regardless of where the continue is placed before it, but the switch executes as expected.

Your expectation is that it doesn't execute? You're setting $count to "-1", then increment it with $count++. In my book, $count would then be 0, which is not greater than 0, which means the if condition is true?

**EDIT**: based on the information I got from the comment, you're not using the contents of the first line, and you're using $count merely to keep track of the number of iterations done? If so; what's wrong with the following:

```
<?php

$lines = array(
    'first',
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz',
    'item1'
);

$first = array_shift( $lines ); // remove it if you don't use it?
$lines = array_filter( $lines ); // remove empty lines.
$count = 0; // set count to 0, although you could just count( $lines ) as well.

foreach ($lines as $item){
    $count ++;
    echo '-not the first line-'."\n";

    if( $item === 'item1' ) {
        echo "item 1 found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @BarryLangerak: yes, but it needs to check if the string is empty first..if the string is empty, `continue` and ignore the rest of the loop. all of the rest of the loop ignored, except for the `count > 0' part. the `count > 0` is used to check if it's the first line and keep track of the amount of iterations later in the code

Comment: ah. That explains a little. Have you ever heard of the function `array_shift( )`?

Answer (score 3):

Your 2nd example will work for you even if you don't have the continue-block.

```
$count = -1;
foreach ($lines as $item){
    $count++;

    switch ($item){
        case "item1":
            if ($count > 0){
                echo '-not the first line-';  // executes as expected
            }
            echo "item 1 found";
        break;
    }
}
```

if your `$item == ""` it is obviously `$item != "item1"` so the only case will not be executed. in your example code that's equivalent to having a continue before. my guess is that your $item is not "" as you expect. try `var_dump($item)` it.

Edit1: local test

```
<pre><?php

$lines = array("", "", "John Doe", "", "2011", "", "", "item1");

$count = -1;
foreach ($lines as $item){
    $count++;

    if ($item == ""){
        echo "\t(skipping empty item)\n";
        continue;  // don't process empty items
    }
    if ($count > 0){
        echo "-not the first line-\n";
    }
    else
        echo $item." is the first line\n";

    switch ($item){
        case "item1":
            echo "item 1 found\n";
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

will output

```
    (skipping empty item)
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
    (skipping empty item)
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
item 1 found
```

having

```
$lines = array("foobar", "", "John Doe", "", "2011", "", "", "item1");
```

will output

```
foobar is the first line
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
    (skipping empty item)
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
item 1 found
```

move `$count++;` below the continue-statement, to make it work.

```
<pre><?php

$lines = array("", "", "John Doe", "", "2011", "", "", "item1");

$count = -1;
foreach ($lines as $item){

    if ($item == ""){
        echo "\t(skipping empty item)\n";
        continue;  // don't process empty items
    }
    $count++;
    if ($count > 0){
        echo "-not the first line-\n";
    }
    else
        echo $item." is the first line\n";

    switch ($item){
        case "item1":
            echo "item 1 found\n";
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

output

```
    (skipping empty item)
    (skipping empty item)
John Doe is the first line
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
    (skipping empty item)
    (skipping empty item)
-not the first line-
item 1 found
```

Comment: vardump on it returns `string(0) ""` for all the empty strings. even if that was the issue, why would it then work within the `switch`?

Comment: @user1166877 I'm pretty confused which part of the code has the problem, and what the problem actually is. Could you show an example output from your code and then the output that you expect it to give?

Comment: using your `continue`-block your output statements will only **not be executed** if `$item == ""`. in the `switch`-block in my example the output statements will only **be executed** if `$item == "item1"`. if your `$item = " "` for example, the `continue`-block will not be executed because `" " != ""`, but the "item1"-case will also not be executed because `" " != "item1"`. let's see some example for your $lines variable, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Basti: with regards to your orignal post, i think you misunderstood my code...there was only 1 `case` because i felt irrelevant to the question to type out all the `case`'s. In my real code there are 5 `case`'s. the `if (count > 0)` and `switch` is only supposed to be reached if the string is not empty

Comment: @Basti: i realise that "" != " ". the string is definately empty.

Comment: that doesn't change the issue. just have an $item that is `$item != ""` and does not match any of your `case`s. please just provide the variable $lines, a desired output and the actual output so we can see the problem.

Comment: @Basti: in your original post you say that my second piece of code will work even if i don't have a continue block..while this is true, i don't really think it a too good idea to copy-paste code into each `case`; I would rather try find out why my empty strings are ignored